# Assigning value to function as object property within for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array of objects. One object property is a function, which I want to change value of depending on which number in the array the object is.

When I try to use the 'i' value from the for loop, this is not being maintained in the function as a number. It is remaining a variable.

```
var array = []; 
for (var i = 0; i<number; i++){
array[i].someFunction = function(i) {console.log(i)}}
```

However, when I call the value held in that property (i.e.):

```
console.log(array[2].someFunction)
```

It returns `{console.log(i)}` instead of `{console.log(2)}` which is what I want it to do.

Comment: You need to call `someFunction`. And use `let` instead of `var i`. Your current loop crashes because it is trying to set `someFunction()` of  `undefined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

It's still referencing i, which has since changed to (number - 1). Save the value somewhere you know it's not subject to change- perhaps in the object itself:

```js
var array = [{}, {}, {}];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i].index = i;
    array[i].someFunction = function(){console.log(this.index);}
}

//and see that it's working...
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i].someFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you had some problems in your code, like:

- not defining `number`
- using `var` instead of `let`
- not defining the object
- using the same value as parameter of the function

here you have the working solution.

```js
var array = [];
// numbers was not defined.
const number = 10;

// use let instead of var
for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  // you are not instantiating your object, here is an example.
  array[i] = {
    "foo": "bar",
    "index": i,
  }
  // you have to change i to j, because if you use i
  // it will be the parameter of the function
  array[i].someFunction = function(j) {
    console.log('index: ', i);
    console.log('parameter: ', j)
  }
}
// we see the function
console.log(array[2].someFunction)

// we call the function succesfully
array[2].someFunction(100);
```